# Delete data from Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to delete data from Oracle tables which I use to store data.

```
  -- TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP1 ON AGENT_HISTORY (AGENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE AGENT_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY8 PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- TABLE CPU_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE CPU_HISTORY(
  CPU_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CPU_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE CPU_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP5 ON CPU_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE CPU_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE CPU_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY9 PRIMARY KEY (CPU_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY(
  CPU_TEMP_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  CPU_TEMP_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CPU_TEMP_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP7 ON CPU_TEMP_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE CPU_TEMP_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY10 PRIMARY KEY (CPU_TEMP_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY(
  MEMORY_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  MEMORY_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  MEMORY_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP9 ON MEMORY_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE MEMORY_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY11 PRIMARY KEY (MEMORY_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE DISK_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE DISK_HISTORY(
  DISK_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  DISK_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  DISK_READ_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL,
  DISK_WRITE_VALUE NUMBER
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE DISK_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP10 ON DISK_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE DISK_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE DISK_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY12 PRIMARY KEY (DISK_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY(
  NETWORK_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  ADAPTER_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  TRANSMITBYTES NUMBER NOT NULL,
  TRANSMITSPEED NUMBER,
  RECEIVESPEED NUMBER,
  RECEIVEBYTES NUMBER
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP11 ON NETWORK_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE NETWORK_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY13 PRIMARY KEY (NETWORK_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE SWAP_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE SWAP_HISTORY(
  SWAP_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  SWAP_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  SWAP_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE SWAP_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP13 ON SWAP_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE SWAP_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE SWAP_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY14 PRIMARY KEY (SWAP_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY(
  CONNECTIONS_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  CONNECTIONS_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  CONNECTIONS_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP14 ON CONNECTIONS_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE CONNECTIONS_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY15 PRIMARY KEY (CONNECTIONS_HISTORY_ID)
/

-- TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY

CREATE TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY(
  PARTITIONS_HISTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_ID INTEGER,
  PARTITIONS_NAME VARCHAR2(50 ) NOT NULL,
  PARTITIONS_VALUE NUMBER NOT NULL
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP15 ON PARTITIONS_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE PARTITIONS_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY16 PRIMARY KEY (PARTITIONS_HISTORY_ID)
/
```

How I can delete all data from the Oracle tables older than 3 months with one SQL query?

Can I use only one SQL query? Maybe with cascade delete?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should add a foreign key constraint that will delete child records when you delete their corresponding parent records:

```
ALTER TABLE CPU_HISTORY 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CPU_HIST_EVENT_ID
FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID)
     REFERENCES AGENT_HISTORY (EVENT_ID)
     ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

You would execute the above statement only once.

Note that if you have records in CPU_HISTORY that have an unknown EVENT_ID (not in AGENT_HISTORY), the above statement will fail. In that case clean up these orphan records first.

Repeat this for all tables that have an EVENT_ID referring to AGENT_HISTORY. Note that you need to name all these foreign keys with a unique name.

Then with this delete:

```
DELETE 
FROM    AGENT_HISTORY
WHERE   EVENT_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3);
```

...the corresponding records (with same EVENT_ID) will be deleted from CPU_HISTORY (and other tables where you have applied the same `CASCADE DELETE` foreign key).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify?